# How to get replies with twitterizer C#

Tags: c#, twitterizer

I am willing to know how can I get the replies of a tweet?

I am not quite sure if this could be accomplished by using a trend or maybe passing a different API URL in an option file to the Retweets methos, I don't know by hard how to do it, any assistance will be well received.

Comment: I was able to get the replies of a Tweet using

Comment: TwitterResponse<TwitterSearchResultCollection> replies = TwitterSearch.Search(tokens, "term", options);

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to do a Search:

```
TwitterResponse<TwitterSearchResultCollection> replies = TwitterSearch.Search(tokens, "term", options);
```

And loop thru the results:

```
foreach (var reply in replies.ResponseObject)
                { }
```

Please ensure to use:

```
if (reply.InReplyToScreenName != null && reply.InReplyToScreenName.ToLower().Equals("term"){}
```

To get the replies of the right user (the one that you looked for)
Term is going to be replaced by the ScreenName that you look for i.e.: @rodbh08